# Не подключается css файл в html

Tags: html, css, html5, вёрстка, frontend

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
    <head>
        <title>sass</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="#source/css/style.css" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 class="h1">Hello scss</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
body {
  color: red;
}
```

Стиль не отображается, но если из пути убрать папку #source, то все чинится :/

Comment: папка так и называется `#source`?

Comment: Да, папка так и называется

Comment: Вопрос как сделать чтобы стиль подключился с папкой #source?

Comment: @p1ka # это служебный символ, таким и похожими символами лучше не нужно называть файлы и папки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="%23source/css/style.css" />
```